# How to convert .dat file to .dll file

Tags: qt, dll, icu

I am using Qt 5.1 to create an application. Unfortunately there is a dependency of a dll file (icudt51.dll) with size over 20 MB, and it is not required in my app too. The solution to this problem is to use a reduced sized icudt file. The following [website](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/) generates a reduced version of the file but the file is in dat format. How can I get the dll file.

Answer (score 0):

From the instructions at that web page:

> After the data library package has been downloaded there are two common ways to use the new package.

```
Rebuild ICU: Under this scenario, you unzip the data package into icu/source/data/in to replace the existing data package that comes with a standard source code distribution. Then you use "gmake clean install". This will clean up your previous build of ICU, and it will install the packages as specified by the configure options that you originally used to build ICU.
```

I believe you need to rebuild the dll after replacing the generated .dat file into the source folder icu/source/data/in. The .dat file is not a dll but data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution to this. Simply drop ICU support by recompiling your Qt with "no-icu", then recompile your application with the no-icu build of Qt.

This should get you started:

configure -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -static -platform win32-g++ -c++11 -make libs -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -no-openssl -no-icu -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -no-iconv -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-style-windowsxp
-qt-style-windowsvista -no-opengl -no-openvg -no-dbus

mingw32-make -j8